# Navigation Bar Drop Down Items don't stay visible

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, navigation

Finally got this all layed out and functioning and looking the way I want, and for the last 3 days I've tried to figure out why the menus disappear when you try to select an item from the drop down. I'm at a loss.
The closest I have been able to get is to change the ul ul{display: block;} But, when I do that, is displays all the time, not just on hover.
I've tried to roll back as far as I could, but STILL can't find where or what I changed, because it USED to work with no issues. HELP!

HTML:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>TestSite&reg;</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" href="images/octab.png" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

</head>

<!--BEGIN HEADER-->
<body>
<div class="titlebar">
    <div id="content" style="text-align:right">
    Controls Technical Support: 866-918-1100
    </div>
</div>

<div id="barcontent">
<img src="images/AAON_WattMasterLogo.png" alt="WattMaster Controls, Inc. ">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="">First</a>
                <ul>
                <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Link 2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="">Second</a>
                <ul>
                <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Link 2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="">Third</a>

            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="">Fourth</a>

            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="">Fifth</a>
                <ul>
                <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Link 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Link 3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>

<div id="content">
page content
</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
@import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Volkhov:700,700italic,400italic,400);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald);
@font-face {
font-family : "'Oswald'";
font-style : normal;
font-weight : 400;
src : local('Oswald Regular'), local('Oswald-Regular'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/oswald/v8/Y_TKV6o8WovbUd3m_X9aAA.ttf) format('truetype');
}
.err
{
    font-family : Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size : 12px;
    color: red;
}
body {
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    background-color: #F6F6F6;
    margin: 0 auto;
    }
#content{
    max-width: 1175px;
   margin: 10px auto;
}
#barcontent{
    max-width: 1175px;
   margin: 10px auto;
}
#barcontent img{
    width: 12%;
}
.titlebar{   
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;    
}
/*NAVIGATION BAR CSS*/
nav{
display: flex;
/*background-color: white;*/
width: 85%;
float: right;
}


    /*navbar link color*/
        a {
            color: black;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: block;
        }
    /*top bar selections*/
        ul {
            background: #fff;
            float: left;
            border: 5px solid #eeeeee;
            list-style: none;
            width: 100%;
            margin: 10px auto;
            height: 50px;
            line-height: 50px;
            padding: 0;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            justify-content: space-around;
            flex-wrap: nowrap;
            float:right;
            }



    /*top bar division of selections*/
        li {
            position: relative;
            list-style: none;
            display: inline;
            float: left;
            width: inherit;
            text-align: center;
            border-right: 1px solid #eeeeee;
        }



        ul li:hover >a{
            background:#1475B3;
            color: white;
            list-style-type: none;

        }
        ul ul:hover{
                    display: block;}
        ul ul li{
            display: block;
            padding: 10px 0px;
            color: #a9a9a9;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font: 11px/1.2em "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
            text-align: center;
            background: linear-gradient(to bottom,#f7f7f7 0%,#ffffff 100%);
            width: 100%;

        }


        ul ul {
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            top: 100%;
            display: none;
            border: none;
        }
        /*sets color of drop down links when hovered over*/
        ul ul li:hover{     
            background:#1475B3;

        }
        ul ul li:hover > a{
            color:white;
            display: block;
            }



        li:hover > ul {
            display: block;

        }


        p {
            clear: left;
            padding-top: 1em;
        }

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    nav{
display: flex;
/*background-color: white;*/
width: 100%;
float: right;
}
#barcontent img{
    width: 50%;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its gone just because of missing href value. See in screen shot

[image]

It should be link this if don't want to land on any other page. I hope will help you.

```
<a href="#">Link 1</a>
```